# Getting inline style CSS property

Tags: css, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse inline CSS style and get certain CSS properties. At this point, I am using a wonky regex which is fairly brittle in nature, and was wondering if there's a better way to do things

```
<div class="test" style="border-width: 2.5px; width: 203.5px; margin-right: 2.5px; margin-bottom: 2.5px; display: block;">
Test content
</div>
```

```
match = soup.find("div",{"style":True})
```

`match` contains the "style" attribute and I then end up using regex to get the value for `width`. Is there any other way to get the width property?

Comment: Do you want only to select tags with `width: 203.5px;` or do you want to extract the value of `width:` property?

Comment: @AndrejKesely: I want to extract the value of `width` property and then replace the value of that property with another number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid BeautifulSoup doesn't parse CSS, you have to use CSS parser or stay with string manipulation/regex:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<div class="test" style="border-width: 2.5px; width: 203.5px; margin-right: 2.5px; margin-bottom: 2.5px; display: block;">
Test content
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.select('div[style*="width"]'):
    div['style'] = re.sub(r'((?:^|\s|;)width: )([\d.]+)', lambda g: g.group(1) + str(float(g.group(2))+100), div['style'])

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<div class="test" style="border-width: 2.5px; width: 303.5px; margin-right: 2.5px; margin-bottom: 2.5px; display: block;">
Test content
</div>
```

Comment: The above regex will also capture border-width, which isn't what we want. I'll probably end up playing with the regex a bit to avoid these false captures.

Comment: @anurag I updated my answer. But better solution is to use CSS parser, for example https://tinycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Andrew - thx for the pointer. I am looking at tinycss, cssutils as well as tinycss2.. tinycss2 seems to be the latest and more actively maintained than the first two..